# Various questions on the pic command from the Tikz angles library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, tikz-angles

I have a few questions regarding the `pic` command from the tikz.angles library that I am trying to experiment (the documentation in the Tikz-pgf manual remain very obscur to me).

So here is one bit of code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,shapes,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) node{$\bullet$} node[left]{$O$};
\draw (0,0) circle(2cm);

\draw[->] (0,0)--(2.5,0) coordinate (X) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,2.5) coordinate (Y) node[right]{$y$};

\draw[->,Aquamarine!50!black] (0,0)--($(0,0)!2cm!(4,3)$) node[midway,above left, Aquamarine!50!black]{$r$};
\draw ($(0,0)!2cm!(4,3)$) coordinate (P) node{$\bullet$} node[above right](P){$P$};

\draw[->,thick, Orchid!50!black] ($(0,0)!2cm!(4,3)$) -- ([turn]90:1cm) node[above, Orchid!50!black]{$\overrightarrow{v_e}$};
  \draw    pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, ->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=X--O--P};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that yields me this picture (please note the colours will likely change) :

[image]

There I have two questions

1. Is there any way to use the `pic` command directly with coordinates without naming the points ? I tried various versions of `\draw    pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, ->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
   {angle=(2.5,0)--(0,0)--($(0,0)!2cm!(4,3)$)}` without any success
2. How can I change the color of my `alpha`, I have not found any doc about that.

Then there is a `scope` issue. This figure is in fact part of this one :
[image]
obtained through this code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,shapes,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0,0) coordinate (O) node[above left]{$O$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above]{$z$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right]{$x$};

\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[left]{$\overrightarrow{u'_z}=\overrightarrow{u_z}$};

\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[above left]{$\overrightarrow{u_y}$};
\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[below]{$\overrightarrow{u_x}$};

\begin{scope}[rotate around y=30]
\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[below]{$\overrightarrow{u'_y}$};
\draw[->, red] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[above]{$\overrightarrow{u'_x}$};
\end{scope}

\draw (1.5,2.5,0) node{$\bullet$} node[right]{$P$ (fixe dans $\mathcal{R}_R$)};


\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,yshift=1.0cm]
\draw (0,0) node{$\bullet$} node[left]{$O$};
\draw (0,0) circle(2cm);

\draw[->] (0,0)--(2.5,0) coordinate (X) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,2.5) coordinate (Y) node[right]{$y$};

\draw[->,Aquamarine!50!black] (0,0)--($(0,0)!2cm!(4,3)$) node[midway,above left, Aquamarine!50!black]{$r$};
\draw ($(0,0)!2cm!(4,3)$) coordinate (P) node{$\bullet$} node[above right](P){$P$};

\draw[->,thick, Orchid!50!black] ($(0,0)!2cm!(4,3)$) -- ([turn]90:1cm) node[above, Orchid!50!black]{$\overrightarrow{v_e}$};
  \draw    pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, ->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=X--O--P};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The translation just does not seem to apply to the `pic` command.

3. Any reason for the scope not having any effect ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It seems to me that you must use coordinate names. My guess is that the internals use `\pgfpointanchor` or some such, which requires a named node. It's probably good form to name your coordinates anyway!
2. To make the angle label (say) green, set the `text` property of the pic (or the entire path):

   ```
   \draw pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, text=green, ->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm] {angle=X--O--P};
   ```
3. The pic is drawn relative to the named coordinates you use, which do not translate with a scope. In this case, you have redefined `(X)` and `(P)` for the second half of the picture, but `(O)` is still the origin of the first picture. To get the result you want you can just redefine the coordinate `(O)` as well to be the (translated) origin. For this case though I'd actually suggest using two separate tikz pictures. Then you can arrange, align, and space them any way you want as you would with imported graphics or text).

Comment: How can one change the location of $\alpha$ so as to place it near the anchor?

Comment: @Marion The `angle eccentricity` option controls the label location (distance from the angle vertex as a multiple of `angle radius`) -- is that what you're asking?