# TikZ pic angle not showing up

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

I am trying to label a triangle using the Ti*k*Z pic command, and the angle I am trying to create is not showing up.

Chapter 18 of the Ti*k*Z manual was unclear to me as to how to specify different types of pics.

I also referenced [Various questions on the pic command from the Tikz angles library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336244/various-questions-on-the-pic-command-from-the-tikz-angles-library)

Also, how can I specify a right angle with `\pic` as well - even a manual reference would be very helpful.
Here's an MWE and an example of what the finished product will look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,trig format=rad]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (pi/4:1);
    \coordinate (C) at (pi/4:1|-0,0);
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw pic["$\scriptstyle\frac{\pi}{4}$",-,angle eccentricity=1, angle radius=0.5cm]{angle=C--A--B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You get the official manual by doing `texdoc pgfmanual`. The [unofficial web manual](https://tikz.dev/library-angle) is much more handy, though.

Comment: You need `draw` as part of the pic's option, not as the path options (`\draw` = `\path[draw]`). Setting the `trig format` to `rad` might mess things up as well but let's do one step at a time.

Comment: thank you @Qrrbrbirlbel , adding draw made the angle show up and changing from radians to degrees also helped. Would you mind also letting me know how to make it a right angle? Thank you very much again for your help.

Comment: You also need to load the `quotes` library (unless `tkz-euclide` does that for you).

Comment: Change `angle=A--B--C` to `right angle=A--B--C`. This is literally on the page @Qrrbrbirlbel linked to.

Comment: Thank you, I should have been more prudent in my reading of the answers

Comment: That said, there are some `pic` things which don't work as the manual claims (or at all, as far as I know). In particular, naming them fails badly (unless this has been fixed since I last checked). I tore my hair out trying to figure out what I was doing wrong ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is almost a way to do it in `Tikz`. See my remarks on residual problems, below.

#### General

To me it looks like you try mixing a `Tikz` approach with the way `tikz-euclide` is doing it. I suggest to decide for one approach only. Both have pros and cons.

For an example close to yours see [p. 117ff, ch. Angles in the euclide-manual](https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide.pdf#subsection.7.4).

[image: manual]

#### Tikz-approach

Let's highlight the relevant parts from my code below.

Preamble: class `standalone` is more convenient when developing drawings. Here you also find the two required `tikzlibraries`, already mentioned in the comments:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% easier for development
\usetikzlibrary{angles}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual
```

Your questions related to using `\pic`s can be reduced to defining useful styles, here `pi4` and `pi2`. A useful way is to put those formats inside the code first, and move repetetive parts into a style statement, later, to simplify code. I dropped scale when challanging your way of defining the coordinates: they don't seem to impact the residual problems, see below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=3,% <<<
        trig format=rad,
        pi4/.style={draw,angle radius=7mm,"$\frac{\pi}{4}$",font=\tiny},
        pi2/.style={draw,angle radius=3mm}  
    ]
```

For my orientation I put labels to your points. Read that path-statement as "move to .. and put a label there, then move to ..." (You could have included them already when you drew your triangle, but that tends to be a matter of taste and experience.)

```
    \draw (A) node[left] {A}   (B) node[above] {B}   (C) node [right] {C};
```

So finally let's draw and label the arcs. Your code now collapses like this, where you control appearance of arrows as you would when drawing simple lines:

```
    \pic[pi4,<->]   {angle=C--A--B};
    \pic[pi4]       {angle=A--B--C};
    \pic[pi2]       {right angle=B--C--A};
```

#### Residual problems

SOLVED: comment out or delete `trig format=rad,`, [see comment from John](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692948/tikz-pic-angle-not-showing-up/692969?noredirect=1#comment1719614_692969).

For some funny reason the arcs center seem to refer to some other points than your intended coordinates. I'm afraid, somebody else must solve this problem.

Also reverting the order into e.g. `{angle=B--A--C};` results in a compile error.

#### Result and code

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% easier for development
\usetikzlibrary{angles}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=3,% <<<
        trig format=rad,
        pi4/.style={draw,angle radius=7mm,"$\frac{\pi}{4}$",font=\tiny},
        pi2/.style={draw,angle radius=3mm}  
    ]
    % ~~~ coordinates ~~~~~
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    % ~~~ do these definitions cause the funny arcs? ~~~~
%    \coordinate (B) at (pi/4:1);
%    \coordinate (C) at (pi/4:1|-0,0);
    % ~~~ no ... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (C) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,5);
    
    % ~~~ triangle with labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    
    % ... read as "move to (A), place a node there, move to (B) ...
    \draw (A) node[left] {A}   (B) node[above] {B}   (C) node [right] {C};
    

    \pic[pi4,<->]   {angle=C--A--B};
    \pic[pi4]       {angle=A--B--C};
    \pic[pi2]       {right angle=B--C--A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### P.S.

Just to highlight the pecularity, I added some older code, which worked ...

[image: results]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% easier for development
\usetikzlibrary{angles}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=3,% <<<
        trig format=rad,
        pi4/.style={draw,angle radius=7mm,"$\frac{\pi}{4}$",font=\tiny},
        pi2/.style={draw,angle radius=3mm}  
    ]
    % ~~~ coordinates ~~~~~
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    % ~~~ does this definition causes the funny arcs? ~~~~
%    \coordinate (B) at (pi/4:1);
%    \coordinate (C) at (pi/4:1|-0,0);
    % ~~~ no ... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (C) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,5);
    
    % ~~~ triangle with labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    
    % ... read as "move to (A), place a node there, move to (B) ...
    \draw (A) node[left] {A}   (B) node[above] {B}   (C) node [right] {C};
    

    \pic[pi4,<->]   {angle=C--A--B};
    \pic[pi4]       {angle=A--B--C};
    \pic[pi2]       {right angle=B--C--A};
\end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (6,3);

    \draw[thick] (P) node[left] {P}--(Q)--(R)--cycle;
    
    \pic[draw,->]   {angle=R--Q--P};
    \pic[draw,angle radius=1.5cm,<->,"$\psi$"] 
                    {angle=Q--P--R};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works if you comment out `trig format=rad,`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, right, that works : )

Comment: Or use `[trig fomrat=deg]` in a scope or `\path`.  I uspect this is a bug that can and will be fiixed RSN.